# Python, JSON and Multiple Objects

Tags: json, python-3.x

Python3 coding:

I am trying to extract fields from a web JSON response but just can't see how to iterate the objects.  The JSON has some standard entries, then fires into a list of objects and back out to more standard entries.  I have summarised this below:

```
{
  "accepted_count": 38526,
  "cpu_total": 6,
  "cpus": [
    {
      "device_id": 0,
      "hashrate": 61382378,
    },
    {
      "device_id": 1,
      "hashrate": 61439706,
    },
    {
      "device_id": 2,
      "hashrate": 61433822,
    },
    {
      "device_id": 3,
      "hashrate": 61229485,
    },
    {
      "device_id": 4,
      "hashrate": 61183044,
    },
    {
      "device_id": 5,
      "hashrate": 23950340,
    }
  ],
  "hashrate": 330618775,
  "invalid_count": 0,
  "os": "win",
  }
}
```

I can load this data from the web site using (webURL is the web site returning the json):

```
s = requests.Session()
jsonData = s.get(webURL)
data = jsonData.json()
```

The problem is if I ask for **data['hashrate']** I just get the hashrate value at the very bottom (330618775).  I need to work out how to extract each of the hashrate values in the objects and be able to relate it to the device_id value in the same object.

I have tried the likes of :

```
data[0]['hashrate']
```

but I just get an error :
**KeyError: '0'**

Same if the key is 1, 2 etc

I am at a loss, any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance
Guy

Comment: `data['cpus'][0]['hashrate']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When searching for techniques to access a `json` data structure in python, it may be more helpful to instead learn about python collections such as `list`s and `dict`s.

When parsed, in python, they are nothing more than that.

So if you look at your top level collection, it is represented by curly braces or `{}`. This is the representation of a python `dict`, basically a `{key: value}` list. To access elements, you reference the key who's value you want to access.

```
print(data["cpus"])
```

In your example the keys are `"accepted_count"`, `"cpu_total"`, `"cpus"`, `"hashrate"`, `"invalid_count"`, and `"os"` respectively.

The value of the `"cpus"` key is represented by `[]` which represents a python `list`. A `list` is accessed by its integer index.

```
cpus = data["cpus"]
print(cpus[0])
```

Finally, each element in the `list` is a `dict` consisting of 2 keys, which as you might have guessed, are accessed by referencing the key you want.

```
cpus = data["cpus"]
first_cpu = cpus[0]
print(first_cpu["hashrate"])
```

Combined:

```
data = {
    "accepted_count": 38526,
    "cpu_total": 6,
    "cpus": [
        {
            "device_id": 0,
            "hashrate": 61382378,
        },
        {
            "device_id": 1,
            "hashrate": 61439706,
        },
        {
            "device_id": 2,
            "hashrate": 61433822,
        },
        {
            "device_id": 3,
            "hashrate": 61229485,
        },
        {
            "device_id": 4,
            "hashrate": 61183044,
        },
        {
            "device_id": 5,
            "hashrate": 23950340,
        }
    ],
    "hashrate": 330618775,
    "invalid_count": 0,
    "os": "win"
}

print(data['cpus'][0]['hashrate'])
```

Comment: You are a legend.  My question is now why I couldn't find a web site that explained this as well as you just did.  Hats off and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> but I just get an error : KeyError: '0'
> data[0]['hashrate']

The 'hashrate' you're trying to find are in a array on the `cpus` key, so you'll need to loop over the array:

---

I've created a file called `input.json` and a simple script like so:

```py
import json

with open('input.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

    for cpu in d['cpus']:
        print("ID: {:d} || HashRate: {:d}".format(cpu['device_id'], cpu['hashrate']))
```

This will produce:

```
ID: 0 || HashRate: 61382378
ID: 1 || HashRate: 61439706
ID: 2 || HashRate: 61433822
ID: 3 || HashRate: 61229485
ID: 4 || HashRate: 61183044
ID: 5 || HashRate: 23950340
```

You can easily sum up the total hashrate if needed

Comment: Thank you for answering, you just taught an old dog a new trick :)

Comment: Yeah I  did, but it seems I am too new for my vote to count.

Comment: I Understand @GuyBarwood. I you want you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.